# Find Hilbert Basis of Magic Square Equations

Tags: groebner-basis, magic-square

How to find Hilbert basis of these equations?

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = x_4 + x_ 5 + x_6 = x_7 + x_8 + x_9 $

$x_1 + x_4 + x_7 = x_2 + x_ 5 + x_8 = x_3 + x_6 + x_9 $

Comment: Do you really need a Gröbner basis here? This is a homogeneous linear system, so the tools from linear algebra give you a basis for the solution space, no?

Comment: In the lecture, it was said that I have to follow these steps (Translation to ideal -> Term ordering -> Find the Grobner basis -> select the leading terms as solution) .

Answer (score 0):

The first $3$ polynomials are already orthogonal
$$p_1=x_1+x_2+x_3$$
$$p_2=x_4+x_5+x_6$$
$$p_3=x_7+x_8+x_9$$
The space only has $5$ dimensions. As was pointed out, linear algebra suffices to determine $2$ more orthogonal polynomials
$$p_4=2x_1-x_2-x_3+2x_4-x_5-x_6+2x_7-x_8-x_9$$
$$p_5=x_2-x_3+x_5-x_6+x_8-x_9$$
Now we verify that the polynomials in question are in the space spanned by the $p_i$
$$x_1+x_4+x_7=\frac{1}{3}(p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4)$$
$$x_2+x_5+x_8=\frac{1}{8}(2p_1+2p_2+2p_3-p_4+4p_5)$$
$$x_3+x_6+x_9=\frac{1}{8}(2p_1+2p_2+2p_3-p_4-4p_5)$$